# How to make a symmetric matrix where the sum of each row and column is k when the diagonal elements are certain (not zero) in excel?

Tags: excel, matrix, symmetry

Is there a simple algorithm that can be used in excel to build a symmetric matrix where the sum of each row and column is k when the diagonal elements are determined (not zero)? In other words, if the diagonal elements are determined, fill in the lower triangular matrix, and then transpose the lower triangular matrix, remove the diagonal elements, and merge into a new symmetric matrix, whose the sum of each row and column are all k?

For Example, I have three diagonal elements 2,4,5. Then there is a diagonal matrix in excel.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 |

Then I make links to transpose the lower triangular matrix:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A2 | A3 |
| 0 | 4 | B3 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 |

Then, I think I want to get a link that make the sum of each row and column is k=5:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A2 | A3 |
| (5-SUM(A1:A1))/2 | 4 | B3 |
| A2 | (5-SUM(B1:B2))/1 | 5 |

Then excel will appear that

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.5 | 1.5 |
| 1.5 | 4 | -0.5 |
| 1.5 | -0.5 | 5 |

However, only the first two rows/first two columns of this matrix sum to 5. Does the algorithm I need exist?

Comment: I believe it can be achieved, however your task is not fully determined. What shall be the values in the bottom triangle: manually entered of calculated? If calculated can some of them be random? What shall be the sum of the row and columns?

Comment: Once you have specified the diagonal that only leaves three independent values to determine in a 3X3 symmetric matrix. If the row and column totals are all equal to 5 (say), this would give 6 equations so it would seem to be over-specified - in fact you should be able to work out a unique solution for all 6 of the independent values including the diagonal (you might find that they would all have to be equal to 5/3 !)

Comment: Dear @TomSharpe, Thank you very much for your reminding, which makes me think about how to solve this problem with equations. First of all, your statement is inaccurate. The matrix is a symmetric matrix, and the number of equations to be solved should only be 3, that is, the sum of the first row, the second row, the third row is 5, or the sum of the first column, the second column, the third column is 5. Because in this 3X3 matrix, there are 3 degrees of freedom (3 freely variable lower triangular elements).

Comment: Therefore, there should be a set of equations that can completely determine these three free variables. 2+A2+A3=5;  4+A2+B3=5;  5+A3+B3=5. Then we have A2=2, A3=-1, B3=1.  Second, in a 4X4 matrix, there are 6 free variables and 4 equations to solve. So there should be an infinite set of solutions, and I only need one of them to fill the lower triangular matrix. Is there an easy way in excel to determine this trigonometric matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fill the lower triangular matrix of a given nXn symmetric matrix with diagonal elements such that the sum of the elements in each column or row of the matrix is k.
First, fill the rest of the lower triangular matrix with any number so that the matrix has only n unknowns. These n unknowns are best presented as |-, so that excel can operate easily.
Second, the lower half of the n unknowns of type |- (line 4 and the following) can be determined for n-3 unknowns using k-sum(Bi:Ni), such that only 3 unknowns remain.
Third, if you look closely at these three unknowns, you can see that they just form the solution for the 3X3 matrix that I mentioned in the problem. Specifically, the principal diagonal elements of the 3X3 matrix.
in which the principal diagonal elements of the 3X3 matrix are

```
X1=SUM(A1,D1:N1)，X2=SUM(B2,D2:N2)，X3=SUM(C3:N3)
```

Fourth, to solve the equations:

```
X1+A2+A3=k
A2+X2+B3=k
A3+B3+X3=k
```

Solved:

```
A2=k/2+(-X1-X2+X3)/2
A3=k/2+(-X1+X2-X3)/2
B3=k/2+(X1-X2-X3)/2
```

The solution of the equations is used to fill in the last three unknowns to obtain the symmetric matrix required by the problem.

Example:

First, I have three diagonal elements 2,4,5,6,7. Then there is a diagonal matrix in excel.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 7 |

Second, make links to transpose the lower triangular matrix:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| 0 | 4 | B3 | B4 | B5 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 | C4 | C5 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | D5 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 |

Third, filling some specific sections of cells, such as 1:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| 0 | 4 | B3 | B4 | B5 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 | C4 | C5 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 6 | D5 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |

Fourth, n-3 elements in line 4 and the following can be determined using k-sum(Bi:Ni):

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| 0 | 4 | B3 | B4 | B5 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 | C4 | C5 |
| k-sum(B4:E4) | 1 | 1 | 6 | D5 |
| k-sum(B5:E5) | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |

Fifth, using the solution of the above equation, filling the rest 3 elements of this matrix.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| k/2+(-X1-X2+X3)/2 | 4 | B3 | B4 | B5 |
| k/2+(-X1+X2-X3)/2 | B3=k/2+(X1-X2-X3)/2 | 5 | C4 | C5 |
| k-sum(B4:E4) | 1 | 1 | 6 | D5 |
| k-sum(B5:E5) | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |

If you substitute X1, X2 and X3, you get

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 |
| k/2+(-SUM(A1,D1:N1)-SUM(B2,D2:N2)+SUM(C3:N3))/2 | 4 | B3 | B4 | B5 |
| k/2+(-SUM(A1,D1:N1)+SUM(B2,D2:N2)-SUM(C3:N3))/2 | B3=k/2+(SUM(A1,D1:N1)-SUM(B2,D2:N2)-SUM(C3:N3))/2 | 5 | C4 | C5 |
| k-sum(B4:E4) | 1 | 1 | 6 | D5 |
| k-sum(B5:E5) | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |

Let's set k=10 in this example, we have:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 7 |

Answer (score 0):

For a 3x3 matrix you need at least 4 known element (e.g. diagonal and one additional cell).

Here is an example setting the 4 elements and having all others are calculated:

[image]

[image]

Or, if you want to have fixed sum:

[image]

[image]

extending that to a bigger matrix requires solving linear equation system, it's not really an Excel problem, more a Math one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, your matrix is not a symmetric matrix. I want to get a symmetric matrix, meaning that once the elements of the lower triangular part of the matrix are determined, the elements of the upper triangular part (which does not contain the diagonal elements) are also determined. Therefore, I want to use Excel to automatically generate the elements of the lower triangular part of the matrix, so that the sum of each row and column of the matrix is k. The method of element generation can be arbitrary.

Comment: you're right, I've overlooked that part. Please see update

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that we can solve this 3X3 matrix problem using equations. In a3X3 matrix, there are 3 degrees of freedom (3 freely variable lower triangular elements) and. In A3x3 matrix, there are 3 degrees of freedom (3 freely variable lower triangular elements) and. Therefore, there should be a set of equations that can completely determine these three free variables. For example,  2+A2+A3=5;  4+A2+B3=5;  5+A3+B3=5. Then we have A2=2, A3=-1, B3=1.

Comment: Then, in a 4X4 matrix, there are 6 free variables and 4 constraint equations to solve. In a 5X5 matrix, there are 10 free variables and 5 constraint equations. So there should be an infinite set of solutions,  and I only need one of them to fill the lower triangular matrix. Is there an easy way in excel to determine this  matrix?

Comment: Last but not least, I agree with you. This problem is both a math problem and an excel problem. I expect to get a symmetric matrix that meets the requirements, and I also want to fill the elements of a symmetric matrix to be easy to manipulate in excel.

Comment: no, there is no easy way for that in Excel without solving the equations first on paper.

Comment: I think I find an easy way to make the matrix now. Please read my answer.